# Does many "SERVER.TRANSFER"'s (in "case") in ASP classic hurt the performance of the server?

Tags: asp-classic, server.transfer

I want to build this page with ASP classic:

```
<%
Dim depart

depart = 5


Select Case depart
    Case 1
        Server.Trasnfer "/check/noam/newDesign/test1.asp"
    Case 2
        Server.Trasnfer "/check/noam/newDesign/test2.asp"
    Case 3
        Server.Trasnfer "/check/noam/newDesign/test3.asp"
    Case 4
        Server.Trasnfer "/check/noam/newDesign/test4.asp"
    Case 5
        Server.Trasnfer "/check/noam/newDesign/test5.asp"
    Case 6
        Server.Trasnfer "/check/noam/newDesign/test6.asp"
    Case 7
        Server.Trasnfer "/check/noam/newDesign/test7.asp"
    Case 8
        Server.Trasnfer "/check/noam/newDesign/test8.asp"
End Select
%>
```

And I like to know if the server in the background need to enter to every "Server.Transfer" or he will enter only to the "Server.Transfer" in the right case?
I need to know that because I like to know if the server will get bad performance with this solution (We will have more and more case in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It will only enter the first matching case. The interpreter will skip over non-matching cases until this.

Comment: What about the compiler? he will enter all the cases?
You can see the answer I got about the same code with "include": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412068/does-many-includes-in-case-in-asp-classic-hurt-the-performance-of-the-serve/11413314#11413314

Comment: That's a very different question. Includes are included before the interpreter runs. Classic ASP runs VBScript as an interpreted rather than a compiled language (note that it's not inherent to the language but to the platform it is run on). Each line is compiled and executed by the interpreter as it hits it. If the interpreter doesn't hit a line, it isn't compiled and run.